# Don't display the UISearchController table until the search button is tapped

Tags: ios, uisearchcontroller

It seems that the default behavior of the `UISearchController` is to display an empty table as soon as characters are entered in the `UISearchBar`. The search I'm implementing doesn't search as the characters are entered, but it searches when the Search button is tapped.

Because of this, I don't want to display an empty table until the actual search happens. How do I make this happen?

I've tried to set the table hidden until the search button is tapped, but it doesn't seem like the empty table that appears is the same as the `UISearchController` table, because none of the datasource methods are called on that table.

Comment: i'm a little confused on your search button, are you using the searchbar.showSearchResultsButton to initiate the search or a custom uibutton elsewhere?

Comment: I have a `UIBBarButtonItem` in my nav bar, which is a system item of type UIBarButtonSystemItemSearch. When that is tapped, I present the `UISearchController`. This shows dims the background and a search bar appears over the nav bar. Right when a character is typed into the search bar, the empty table view background appears. I don't want the empty table to appear until I actually tap the search button on the on-screen keyboard.

Comment: @MDB983 To further understand what I mean, you can see it happen in the search bar for the standard iOS Calendar. That doesn't show the table until search results have been found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The empty table view you are seeing is from your search results controller, which is "immediately" displayed by UISearchController "when the user enters text in the search bar". ([source](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uisearchcontroller/1618656-obscuresbackgroundduringpresenta))

Hiding the table view in your search results controller until you are ready to show it would seem to be the easiest solution.  But as you discovered, upon displaying the search results controller, UISearchController sets the value of the `isHidden` property on the root view to `false`.  In my debugging session, UISearchController behaved this way every time the search bar began editing or the search text changed, by calling a private method named `_updateVisibilityOfSearchResultsForSearchBar:`.

You can work around that behaviour by adding the table view in the search results controller as a subview of the root view (and then hiding or showing the table view as necessary), or by adjusting the value of the `alpha` property for the root view (which, unlike `isHidden`, can be animated).

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't solve my problem. From the docs: `This property controls only whether the original view controller is initially obscured. When the user enters text in the search bar, the search controller immediately displays the search results controller with the results.` The second sentence is the scenario I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Looks like setting the alpha value of the table view is what did the trick (I only tried setting it to hidden before). So now I'm setting it's alpha to 0 initially until they actually search and when they clear the text, and then setting it to 1 right when they search. If you update your answer, the bounty is all yours!

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can do work around like creating a UIView and adding as subview over the tableview to make it hidden. Once user clicks on search button remove that view.

Comment: I don't think this will work, since I only want to dim the background views so that they are still visible while typing into the search bar. Maybe I'm misinterpreting your solution... care to share an example?